# 負の値をとる投票数の英訳

Tags: 専門用語, 英語

stackoverflowのような投票機能をruby on railsで実装しようとしています。
「投票数」を意味するカラムを設定するのですが、英訳はvote countで違和感ないでしょうか。
反対票しか入らなかった場合、投票数は負の値をとります。
countは暗に非負の値をさしていないか気にしています。
のちのち他のエンジニアがvote_countというカラムをみたときに、これは非負だ、というように思ってしまわないかが気になっています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stackoverflowのソースを覗いてみると、該当箇所(数字の部分)は**upvoteCount**となっています。
ちなみにプラス投票が「vote-up」、マイナス投票は「vote-down」のようです。

Comment: stackoverflowでは**upvoteCount**と命名されているのですね。**upvote**自体は**賛成票**という意味があるようです。stackoverflowにならい、投票数は**vote_count**で進めていきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

投票というと、紙の数を数えるイメージが一般的と思いますので、
説明がない限り、多くの人は、0以上を想定するかと思います。

気になったのが、反対票しかない場合に負の値をとる、という点です。
賛成票と反対票の両方があった時、引き算が発生する？と
見ている側が考えてしまう可能性があると思います。

Comment: 投票という行為は負の値は通常取らないので説明が必須ということで理解しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

総数という意味で **vote_total** としても良いかもしれませんね。

Comment: **vote_total**、こちらの案も捨てがたいですが、stackoverflowにならい**vote_count**としようと思います。ありがとうございました。